# Podman - generate ENV vars with secrets from file

Tags: environment-variables, containers, key, podman

Podman allows the use of a *secret*. This allows you to pass sensitive values, like credentials or API keys, to a container while running it, but excludes them from commits or exports.

So far I've been using the following format to include a config file with credentials as a secret config file within the container.

```bash
podman secret create my_creds /path/to/my/credfile.txt
podman run ... --secret=my_creds,mode=0400 ... container --credentials /run/secrets/my_creds
```

But now I'm confronted with a container that forces me to either include the credentials in a big config file (which I don't want to fully *store* in a secret) or via environment variables.

Podman does have an option to import secrets into a container as environment variables.
However, the list of credentials I need to import is quite large, so I'd need to add quite a lot of lines creating secrets in my service file.

So my question now is: is there a way to take a file containing secrets stored as `KEY=VALUE` and import each line as a secret env variable in a podman container?

EDIT:

Currently I hacked together the following *solution*

```
ExecStartPre=-for l in $(cat /path/to/my/credfile.txt); do \
              echo $l | cut -d'=' -f 2 | /usr/bin/podman secret create $(echo $l | cut -d'=' -f 1 -) -; done


ExecStopPost=-for l in $(cat /path/to/my/credfile.txt); do \
              /usr/bin/podman secret rm $(echo $l | cut -d'=' -f 1 -); done
```

I still need to manually add all the `--secret=SECRET_NAME,type=env` params.